# Problema al poner un botón en el dashboard de un plugin wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugin

Estoy haciendo un plugin de worpress que añade una pagina de configuración en el dashboard y en esta pagina voy a poner un botón que ejecute una función. Investigando he encontrado que lo mejor es usar jquery y de hecho encontré otro plugin que hace algo similar y copie algo de código, además de otras cosas que he encontrado en internet. Pero no logro hacer que se ejecute un código al apretar el botón. Dejo los archivos de lo que tengo hecho, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

El archivo principal PHP tiene esto:

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu','Friend_menu_opciones');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_file');

function load_file( ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'Friend-code', plugins_url( '/friend_code.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), 1.0, true );
}

function Friend_menu_opciones( ) {
  add_users_page( 'BP friends admin', 'BP friends admin', 'administrator', 'Plugin', 'Friend_opciones');
}

function Friend_opciones( ) {
?>

<h3> BP Friends admin</h3>
<h4>Primer usuario </h4><input type="text" id="Usuario1" value="Primer usuario" />
<br/>
<h4>Segundo usuario </h4><input type="text" id="Usuario2" value="Segundo usuario" />
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="Boton1" class="button"><?php _e( 'Click' );?></button>

<?php
}
?>
```

el archivo friend_code.js contiene esto

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
  $( '#Boton1' ).on( 'click', function( event ) { alert( "Si pasa por aqui1" ); } );
} );
```

No logro que se ejecute esta ultima función que por ahora sólo imprime el texto "Si pasa por aqui1"

Ya intente haciendolo sin el archivo js y poniendo el código jQuery en un scrypt después del botón y así si funciona, pero quiero hacerlo con un archivo independiente.

Comment: Si dices que te funciona sin el archivo .js, es posible que: A. El `/` sobra al inicio de la llamada: `plugins_url( '/friend_code.js'...` o bien B. El archivo no está en el lugar adecuado, es decir, en la carpeta que tengas dedicada a tu plugin. Supongamos que la carpeta se llame `tu-plugin`, el .js debe estar allí:  `wp-content/plugins/tu-plugin/friend_code.js` C. Para probar que la ruta se está creando bien puedes hacer un `echo plugins_url( '/friend_code.js', __FILE__)` dentro de la función `load_file()` y ver que la ruta está bien, sin `/` de más o de menos...

Answer (score 0):

revisa si el .js esta en un subdirectorio, probablemnte te falta est, por ejemplo:

```
function load_file( ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'Friend-code', plugins_url( 'js/friend_code.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), 1.0, true );
}
```

o si esta en el directorio del plugin.php debe ir sin la /:

```
function load_file( ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'Friend-code', plugins_url( 'friend_code.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), 1.0, true );
}
```